# Is there a lightweight tool for web browsing automation from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, chrome, browser, headless, selenium

I'm aware of Selenium python library or headless chromium webdriver, but those solutions are heavy and clunky to interface from a shell session (bash, dash, etc.).

Is there a minimal and lightweight tool so I can do browsing automation like `getElementById` or click on buttons or run JavaScript functions utilizing the tool's cli from terminal?

Note that we could `curl` then `awk`, `jq`, `grep` but again, these tools are not specialized for hypertext markup and using regexp for pattern matching HTML parameters is not advised generally.
Additionally a simple HTML parser can't extract into from a Single Page Application webapp.

Comment: Not very sure what you need - you want a tool that is not a library, but it needs to be very much a library? A browser is a stateful thing, so you need some way to interact with a running browser, and the way we do that is through APIs. Some APIs are indeed bash-scriptable, but for this kind of task, bash simply seems to be a completely inadequate tool.

Comment: @Marcus Müller well I'm looking for a CLI browser which doesn't actually render anything buy is only used for querying and automation. The pup tool below could be used for parsing HTML but lacks the features to interact with js components. For example it would not be possible to crawl a SPA.

Comment: yes, but think about what a "CLI" browser would have to be – a fully-fledged, modern browser, running in the background, running JS and everything, with an interface that you can act with from the command line. You'll realize the command line is a very limiting factor here – you need to handle stateful objects! A programming language like Python makes that feasible. A shell does not. You want, functionally, a library for a programming language, but what you say is "I want a stateless interface for my shell", so that makes little sense

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could work for you: https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#xml-html ?

Comment: Thanks. was just reading that list! https://github.com/EricChiang/pup seems to be the best tool at this time to parse HTML. Still none of those tools could simulate interaction (js)...